# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\aiw\index.php

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

```
<?php
echo "<h1>What's The Weather Like?</h1>";
define('API_KEY','********');

$apikey = API_KEY;

$user_ip = '183.91.3.13'; // Remove comment to use this to test when you put 
   this file in localhost
 //$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Comment out this line if you test 
 in your localhost
  $details = 
 json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$user_ip}/json"));
 $city_name = $details->city;
 $loc_details = 
json_decode(file_get_contents("http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/ cities/search?q={$city_name}&apikey={$apikey}"));
 $loc_key = $loc_details[0]->Key;
 $weather_details = 


json_decode(file_get_contents("http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/{$loc_key}?apikey={$apikey}"));
 // print_r($weather_details);
 //  $result = json_decode($data, true);
 echo $weather_details[0]->EffectiveDate;
?>
```

when i try to run the web it shows this problem
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\aiw\index.php on line 16
i hope you dont dislike because i am a new learner

Comment: Provide example of JSON output that you get. Also it is generally bad idea to expose your API keys to public, please replace it with empty string or line of stars

Answer (score 0):

When you decode json in php (using `json_decode`). It will return data as object. If you want data as array you need to pass second param as true. So change your code as below :

```
<?php
echo "<h1>What's The Weather Like?</h1>";
define('API_KEY','**********');

$apikey = API_KEY;

$user_ip = '183.91.3.13'; // Remove comment to use this to test when you put 
   this file in localhost
 //$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Comment out this line if you test 
 in your localhost
  $details = 
 json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$user_ip}/json"));
 $city_name = $details->city;
 $loc_details = 
json_decode(file_get_contents("http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/ cities/search?q={$city_name}&apikey={$apikey}"),true); //change here
 $loc_key = $loc_details[0]['Key'];
 $weather_details = 


json_decode(file_get_contents("http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/{$loc_key}?apikey={$apikey}"),true); //change here
 // print_r($weather_details);
 //  $result = json_decode($data, true);
 echo $weather_details[0]['EffectiveDate'];
?>
```

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://******):failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Unauthorized in C:\xampp\htdocs\aiw\index.php on line 13

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Means it's not an array, it's an object

Change this:

```
 echo $weather_details[0]->EffectiveDate;
```

to this

```
echo $weather_details->Headline->EffectiveDate
```